# how to send compressed file with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I made the following code to send .zip file upon get request to localhost:3000 but the file is being download without filename and without extension

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
    
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("/files/a.rar", {
    extensions:["rar", "zip"]
  })
})
    
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("server connected");
});
```

how i can do this

Comment: Why do this? [Use `express.static` for static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and then use `res.redirect` if you need to serve specific files from "not their actual url"?

Comment: How i can do this

Comment: You read the docs? I linked you to the express.static docs, which is pretty clear, and then instead of res.sendFile to send the file, you use [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) to the file's real URL and the download will happen completely automatically because it's a normal file download now.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `res.download(...)` instead of `res.sendFile(...)`?

I had the same issue and I was able to make it work by using this code block.

```js
import path from 'path';

...

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.download(path.resolve('files/a.rar'), {
        extensions: ["rar", "zip"],
    });
});
```

Give it a try!